# Como manter uma Session após re-executar uma aplicação?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, session, autenticação

No meu projeto em MVC 5, uma sessão com os dados do usuário é criada no login e após a re-execução da aplicação a Session não existe mais, porém, o Coockie de autenticação ainda existe.

O que posso fazer pra manter os dois ativos ou destruir os dois?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Usuario, model.Senha))
    {
        Session.Add("Usuario", new UsuarioModel { Nome = "Eu", Login = "Filipe"});
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Usuario, false);
        if (this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
        {
            return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "O usuário ou a senha são inválidos");

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão o modo de armazenamento da session é ***In-Proc***, ou seja, as informações são armazenadas na memória do servidor, porém, se a aplicação é reiniciada suas informações da session são perdidas.

**Uma alternativa para manter os dados da sua session mesmo depois de reiniciar sua aplicação é mudar o modo de armazenamento da session.**

Você pode usar a opção ***SQLServer*** que armazena as informações de sessão no banco de dados, outra opção é ***StateServer*** que armazena as informações de sessão em um processo separado no servidor, isolando o estado da session de sua aplicação.

Para alterar os modos disponíveis, basta adicionar a tag `<sessionState>` dentro da tag `<system.web>`, no arquivo Web.Config e configurar conforme sua necessidade.

Segue alguns links para maiores detalhes (em inglês):
[**Link1**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx)
[**Link2**](https://www.techcognition.com/post/Configuring-Session-State-in-AspNet-InProc-StateServer-SQLServer-Session-Modes-in-AspNet)
[**Link3**](http://www.itorian.com/2012/09/aspnet-session-states-in-sql-server.html)